# R updates on Ubuntu ('raring')

Tags: r, ubuntu

I attempted to update R on Ubuntu by adding the line

deb http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ raring/

To my sources.list file in /etc/apt

However, this is path is not found, since the code 'raring' version of Ubuntu isn't listed as an option on the R updates for ubuntu page http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/
(my choices being lucid, precise, quantal, etc).

Which /bin/linux/ubuntu directory could I use for this update on the 'raring' version?

Comment: Raring stopped being supported in January.  You should upgrade.

Comment: If I upgrade from raring to a more recent version, will I have to create a new sources.list for updates, or concern myself with other back-compatibility issues? Which ubuntu version would give me the smoothest transition from raring?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to upgrade to the newest version? You will, however, have to upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 and then from 13.10 to 14.04. Expect the process to take quite some time, depending on your internet connection.